# How do I pass a grid's Datasource through to the PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, attributes, propertygrid

I have a grid wrapped in a user control. I need to pass the datasource of the grid through the control.

```
// My Pass-Through declaration
public object DataSource
{
    get { return internalGrid.DataSource; }
    set ( internalGrid.DataSource = value; }
}
```

So far, that's the easy part. The datasource of the grid is a plain Object. The pass-through Datasource is also a plain Object.

When I drop a datagrid directly on my form, I can set datasource by selecting one of my binding source objects on my form. However, when I include my custom control, the pass-through datasource is grayed out. I can't select the binding sources.

[image: Note that I can't select a datasource here.]

I'm certain that I am simply missing a property attribute, but I don't know which one(s). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will probably need a `TypeConverter` for that.

Comment: I agree... What class/object to I TypeConvert to/from?